# How do I know if I can play real music on Android?

Tags: android, audio

I want to test the music app with automation.
However, there is no way to verify that the music actually plays.
I created an app using the audio focus.
I think the audio focus is not related to real play back.
Because if it doesn't play, audio focus can hold onto the focus.

So, I want to create an app to confirm playback. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make the test app listen to the microphone. Play some special signal (a sweep or a click of some sort) that can be easily distinguished from the noise in the recorded signal.

Comment: The company is so quiet that it can not measure the actual sound. I am still grateful for answering my question.